# How to parse pg_dump all kinds of objects to it own file? Like function, table, view, index etc

Tags: postgresql, parsing, pg-dump

I am trying to parse the pg_dump file to object-own single files, to make it more easier to develop and maintenance.

Here is a example:

```
--
-- Name: u_id; Type: DEFAULT; Schema: sc_udccockpit; Owner: udccockpit
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY alarmentity
    ADD CONSTRAINT alarmentity_pkey PRIMARY KEY (u_id);


--
-- Name: alarmstring_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: sc_udccockpit; Owner: udccockpit; Tablespace: 
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY alarmentity
    ADD CONSTRAINT alarmentity_f_active_description_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (f_active_description_id) REFERENCES alarmstring(u_id);


--
-- Name: alarmentity_f_model_description_id_fkey; Type: FK CONSTRAINT; Schema: sc_udccockpit; Owner: udccockpit
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY alarmentity
    ADD CONSTRAINT alarmentity_f_model_description_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (f_model_description_id) REFERENCES alarmstring(u_id);


--
-- Name: alarmentity_f_module_id_fkey; Type: FK CONSTRAINT; Schema: sc_udccockpit; Owner: udccockpit
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY alarmentity
    ADD CONSTRAINT alarmentity_f_module_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (f_module_id) REFERENCES alarmstring(u_id);


--
-- Name: alarmentity_f_node_name_id_fkey; Type: FK CONSTRAINT; Schema: sc_udccockpit; Owner: udccockpit
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY alarmentity
    ADD CONSTRAINT alarmentity_f_node_name_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (f_node_name_id) REFERENCES alarmstring(u_id);


--
-- Name: alarmentity_f_resource_id_id_fkey; Type: FK CONSTRAINT; Schema: sc_udccockpit; Owner: udccockpit
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY alarmentity
    ADD CONSTRAINT alarmentity_f_resource_id_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (f_resource_id_id) REFERENCES alarmstring(u_id);
```

I want to change it to, for example:
file: alarmentity_pkey.sql and in it only has content like

```
--
-- Name: u_id; Type: DEFAULT; Schema: sc_udccockpit; Owner: udccockpit
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY alarmentity
    ADD CONSTRAINT alarmentity_pkey PRIMARY KEY (u_id);
```

I think what I want is: 
Start with "ALTER TABLE ONLY"
End with ";"
including "CONSTRAINT", "PRIMARY"
extracting word between "CONSTRAINT" and "PRIMARY" as file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer after trying many times. To parse and get the "fkey only" single file, you can use 'awk' command.

```
   function extract_constraint_fkey(){
    awk ' /--/,/\;$/ { str = str ?  str "\n" $0 : $0 } /\;$/ { if( str ~ /FOREIGN KEY/ ) { print str > "database\/constraint\/fkey\/"substr($3,1)".sql" };str = "" };' $1

}
```

You can try to follow this to continue parse the primary key, index, alter sequence and so on which relate to make constraints to tables.

BR// Yuanwen Li